# Accuracy of predicted model in R

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the accuracy of a predicted model with respect to the real case. In this case, I am using linear regression to predict my desired value. Plots show good accuracy between predicted and real models but not as good as my calculation for accuracy suggests. I am using the following code to calculate the accuracy of my model in Rstudio:

```
predicted <- import.list$y1

actual <- import.list$T_stp_cool
comparison <- data.frame(actual,predicted)
difference <- ((actual-predicted)/actual)

accuracy=1-abs(mean(difference))
```

In this case, accuracy is 99% most of the time but comparing the plots of the real case and predicted one does not show 99% accuracy. What's the most accurate way to calculate the accuracy of my model?

Comment: You might want to try `mean(abs(difference))`. By taking the average first you are allowing positive and negative residuals to cancel one another out.

Comment: Thank you!
That worked.